# Why angular returns a function inside the callback function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, syntax

To define an Angular's filter, you should write:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.filter('mix', function () {
    // Why do we return a function here?
    return function (input) {
        var output;
        // doing some business here
        return output;
    };
});
```

Why Angular returns a function inside the callback function passed to the `filter` function? Why not just use that as the placeholder and template of filter definition?
This syntax is not developer friendly at all. What limitations Angular has had to make it use this function nesting? Is it a pattern?

I guess what seems logical and normal (based on heavy use of jQuery and other libraries) is this syntax:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.filter('mix', function (input) {
    var output;
    // doing some business here
    return output;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This all has to do with the way Angular does Dependency Injection.

You want the ability to inject services into the filter but return a function that does not employ dependency injection.

For example, let's say that your filter uses the `$location` service:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.filter('mix', function ($location) {
    // Location got injected.

    // create some private functions here
    function process(input) {
       // do something with the input and $location
    }

    return function (input) {
        return process(input);
    };
});
```

You can also see from this example, doing it this way allows you to create "private" functions only available to this filter.

Comment: So, is it possible to use the `['$location', function() {}]` syntax, and use that function as filter, not a nested function? Does it have anything to do with closures?

Comment: Yes.  If you want to use the array (minify-safe) syntax, it will work here as well.

Comment: And yes, closures is part of it.  My `process()` function is closed over in the returning function.  Any other variables you put in the higher-level function will also get closed over.

Comment: But if you use the `[]` syntax, you still need the nested function.  The '[]' syntax is to allow you to use strings as your DI parameters... mostly for when you minify/uglify the code, the injection parameters don't get clobbered.

Comment: Still seems a little uncomfortable to me. I think I have to refer to the source code. AMAIK, in JavaScript `return function() {}` will create as much closure you want as `return function() { return function() {} }` would create for you.

Comment: But how would you manage your dependency injection?  You don't need this nested function for closures, you need the nested function to close over "private" data and functions AND to apply dependency injection.  You don't want to inject dependencies to the filter function.  You want to inject dependencies into the parent function so that the filter function can use them.